# node.js + imagemagick = Error: spawn identify ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick

Когда я пытаюсь исполнить код

```
imagick.identify(`../temp/${data.name}.${data.format}`, function(err, features) 
{
    console.debug(err)
    console.debug(features)
})
```

Я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn identify ENOENT
    at _errnoException (util.js:992:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:372:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Как можно это исправить?

---

**UPD**: после добавления

```
(function() {
    var childProcess = require("child_process");
    var oldSpawn = childProcess.spawn;
    function mySpawn() {
        console.log('spawn called');
        console.log(arguments);
        var result = oldSpawn.apply(this, arguments);
        return result;
    }
    childProcess.spawn = mySpawn;
})();
```

в начало скрипта в консоль выводится вот это:

```
{ '0': 'identify',
  '1': [ '-verbose', '../temp/1535611966778.png' ] }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27688804/how-do-i-debug-error-spawn-enoent-on-node-js

Comment: @Дмытрык
{ '0': 'identify',
  '1': [ '-verbose', '../temp/1535611966778.png' ] }

Comment: Выглядит так, будто этот пакет пытается запустить линуксовую команду.

Comment: Скорее всего, Вы правы. В файле пакета `imagemagick.js` на 178 строчке поменяйте строку `identify`  на любую другую и запустите. ...  Про этот модуль слышу первый раз...На сколько я понял, прежде чем пользоваться этим модулем, необходимо установить программу `ImageMagick` https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php и возможно потом, необходимо будет указать путь к ней в `identify.path`, но могу и ошибаться. Пробуйте

Comment: Я скачал версию для windows. Теперь самое интересное: я могу запустить magick identify -verbose <путь> вручную через cmd, но при исполнении кода ошибка все равно не исчезает.

Comment: "поиграйтесь" с `identify.path`

Comment: Я понял суть этой ошибки. Она возникает при попытке создать дочерний процесс из команды magick identify. Она идет из пакета child_process.

Comment: Если разобрались - напишете ответ к вопросу с подробным решением проблемы

Comment: Пока еще нет. Я сейчас пробую заставить модуль запускать cmd.exe вызывая нужную мне команду, правда пока что тщетно.

Comment: решение найдено. Правда это ужасный костыль, хотя как единственный вариант на windows сойдет. Сейчас начну оформлять ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге я все же нашел решение. На самом деле это ужасный костыль, хотя как единственное действенное решение под windows сойдет.

1. Скачиваем вот [отсюда](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) пакет `ImageMagick-7.0.8-11-Q16-x64-dll.exe` и устанавливаем его.
2. Находим исполняемый скрипт модуля `imagemagick` -- `imagemagick.js`
3. Заменяем содержимое 24-й строки на `var child = childproc.spawn('cmd.exe', ['/C', file + ' ' + args.join(' ')]);`
4. Заменяем содержимое 178-й строки на `exports.identify.path = 'magick identify';`

У меня это сработало. По видимому, `child_process` не может создавать дочерние процессы из команд. В таком случае мы запускаем процесс cmd.exe и уже ему передаем нашу команду, в данном случае `magick identify`.

P.S. Таким же способом стоит прокачать строку 255 (`convert` -> `magick convert`), дабы не было проблем с выполнением ресайза и прочими командами.